# Add maven build time to jar name build with Spring Boot Maven Plugin

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, executable-jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

How can add maven build time to jar file name using Spring Boot Maven plugin?

I want to achieve something like: *jar_name*-*build_time*.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot Maven Plugin builds jar file with name **${project.build.finalName}**.
This can be configured with non-required property **finalName**.

Maven build time can be used as **${maven.build.timestamp}**

So, putting all things together, all you need to do is append build time to default jar name:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.marand.thinkmed.meds.config.boot.MedsConfigApplication</mainClass>
        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, make sure to change timestamp format so it doesn't violate file naming strategies:

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```